# what is Relation between container class and template in C++

Tags: c++, class, templates

what is relation between container class and template in C++, Can any one give me exact answer with example please thanks

Comment: Sounds like a homework question to me.

Comment: Asking for an "exact answer" is also weird. As if most of the time we just give sort-of appropriate answers that just wave around a lot.

Comment: What is the difference between a car and a vehicle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you must understand that C++ has three different "tiers" of named entities: Values, types, and templates. A value has a type, and objects of a certain type can take many values. (I use the terms "object", "variable" and "named value" synonymously.) Then there are templates -- templates are not types, but rather, they *make* types when instantiated. Templates are essentially code-generation tools (which is why templates themselves can't be "compiled" in C++).

With that in mind, it would probably be accurate to say that libraries contain a few choice *container templates*, and when you instantiate one of them on some type, you get a *container (class)* that describes a data structure that holds elements of your type.

Basically, rather than writing a linked list for integers, and one for floats, and another one for unsigned chars, you realize that all those data structures look *formally* the same, and so you create one single list *template*, which you can then instantiate on integers, floats and unsigned chars (and perhaps a lot more!), and you always end up with the corresponding concrete container class.

I suppose the original name "standard template library" alludes to the fact that it is a collection of class *templates*, many of which were container templates.

Answer (score 0):

Templates are often used to implement container classes. All the container classes in the standard library -- like `vector` -- are templates. Specific instantiations of a templated container class are specialized to contain instances of some  other specific class.

Answer (score 0):

Some container classes are templates (esp. the ones in `std`) and some templates are containers. For example you can google for `std` containers.

Answer (score -1):

A template in C++ is anything whose type can be parameterised.   It's not only classes that can be templates, but functions also.   For example the min function in STL is a template function, but it's not a container class:

```
template <class T> const T& min ( const T& a, const T& b );
```

On the other hand a container class usually describes a container which is not templated.   I don't think the C++ standard library includes any of those.

Comment: On the other hand, containers in `std` are templates. And classes. See `vector`, `list`, `stack`, `set` etc.